# Loading URL(which needs certificates) from webview

Tags: ssl, javafx-2, ssl-certificate

All

I am trying to load public URL from webview. But that page comes blank. On further investigations I came to know that is has certificates installed. Is there any way I can bypass or pass the certificate from the java fx client?

Here is the URL 
 "https://store2.vlab.sapbydesign.com/sap/cp/ui/resources/store/html/Cart.html?pcntry=US&sap-language=EN&solutionid=hci-512g&uid=1381145905976",

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: is it android webview?

Comment: No - It is java fx webview